# ReactJS constants that changes dynamically(Dynamic global)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

What would be the best way, while following React best practices, to define globals that changes according to props provided by a redux state.

For example, let's say I have a metric or imperial toggle value that's dispatched into a persisted redux state. Is it possible to call for a constant that changes its value based on the toggle without providing the current state of the toggle by passing it via props?

My current implementation is doing

`globals.distance(this.props.metric)`

where `this.props.metric` is mapped from the redux state to the component's props. I want to somehow implement subscription to the redux state from within the globals file, so I can just do `constants.distance`. I've tried importing `getState()` as well as subscribing to changes in the redux state, but the problems there is that `getState()` only runs once when the file gets loaded, and I can't seem export constants subscribed to the state since the function returns an unsubscribe function. I can  also create a Component and subscribe that to the redux state, but I can't seem to find an easy way to export constants from within a Component state either.

Comment: "a constant that changes its value" 

Comment: Haha, I know. I'm really just calling it a constant, but it's really more of a dynamic global.

Comment: A constant with a sense of humor ;)

Comment: Why do you need to have this global at all? It already exists in the store, why not use it directly from there?

Comment: Changes it to globals but kept the clickbaity title 

Comment: Because I have other globals too. So depending on the value of metric, I return either mph and miles, or kmh and km. I can of course store all of the possible units into redux, but then I would have to connect all my components to the redux. I want to connect the globals to the store instead of all my components to the store.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find a solution I liked, so I made my [own](https://github.com/en-Zee/Redux-Funk). It's a thin wrapper to connect functions to the Redux store and return a value.